# DB2: Find generated column from Java

Tags: java, db2, resultset

I am working with DB2 table using Java code and using ResultSetMetaData for getting meta data for table. Is there anyway to know if the table has generated column and if yes is there a way i can find out the formula used for it.

Either using ResultSetMetaData or using any other approach is fine as long as it's possible through Java code.

Mehul

Answer (score 0):

Use the System Catalogs. Open the following as a ResultSet in Java

```
    SELECT colname
      FROM SysCat.Columns
      WHERE tabname = ?
        AND tabschema = ?
        AND identity = 'Y'
```

If the ResultSet is empty, your table has no GENERATED columns. Otherwise, you can determine which column name is GENERATED from the output of the above query.

If you are looking for a formula that will 'pre-generate' the next value for the IDENTITY column, there is no way to do that, at least not when the database is hot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. That really helped. Regarding formula, you said, i can't access when database is hot but logically that formula must also be stored somewhere in order for database to pre-generate value so like other meta data i must also be able to access that formula. It is my assumption. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I mean you cannot get the value that is about to be assigned to a GENERATED column while the database is hot. You can certainly discover which columns are IDENTITY columns using the above SQL. The closest you can get is SysCat.Sequences.start, but when the database is hot, that number will often be *higher* than the next number assigned to the IDENTITY column. Proof of this is too long for the margin <bg>